# Array Access Issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to use a dynamically updated accessor for a javascript array inside of an object literal constructor. Both data and index variables are in the same functional scope.

```
var data = [];
var index = 0;

dateKeys.forEach(element=>{

data.push({"date":element,[otherKeys[0]]:currentAccount[index]["2017_Q1"],[otherKeys[1]]:0,[otherKeys[2]]:0,[otherKeys[3]]:0,[otherKeys[4]]:0,[otherKeys[5]]:0})
index = index +1;

})
```

The code above produces the following error message: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'currentAccount[index]["2017_Q1"]')

Yet when I try:

```
 dateKeys.forEach(element=>{
 var index = 0;
 data.push({"date":element,[otherKeys[0]]:currentAccount[index]  ["2017_Q1"],[otherKeys[1]]:0,[otherKeys[2]]:0,[otherKeys[3]]:0,[otherKeys[4]]:0,[otherKeys[5]]:0})
index = index +1;

})
```

I get the correct data for index 0 but it does not update. Why does the scoping seem to make a difference here to the ability to use a variable name in place of a number in the square brackets? I have tried using let, to see if it was a binding issue, but that makes no difference. Is there a solution using vanilla javascript?

Comment: This example is incomplete--it's not clear what `currentAccount`, `otherKeys` or `dateKeys` are. See [mcve] for help on how to write an answerable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are declaring and initializing `index` variable each time when `forEach` callback is called.

For example if `dateKeys` has 5 items, then `element => ...` will be called 5 times and each time creating a new variable `index` and setting it's value 0.

In second case you are never accessing `currentAccount` with `index` value 1.

You are getting this error because `dataKeys`, has more entries than `currentAccount`.

Answer (score 1):

`var` is function-scoped, which means your `index` gets hoisted to the top and out of the loop-block. Each time you loop through `dataKeys`, it will always be referencing the same hoisted `index`.

Use `let` to declare `index` inside `forEach`, or simply expose the `index` argument from `forEach`:

```
dateKeys.forEach((element, index) => {
  // use index here
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are declaring `index` every single time the loop runs - the code inside the function will be executed every time. You need to use the built-in `forEach` index parameter (the second one):

```
dateKeys.forEach((element, index) => {
    data.push({"date":element,[otherKeys[0]]:currentAccount[index]  ["2017_Q1"],[otherKeys[1]]:0,[otherKeys[2]]:0,[otherKeys[3]]:0,[otherKeys[4]]:0,[otherKeys[5]]:0});
});
```